# How do get "value + id " as a value?

Tags: javascript

I want to get value name + id.But how ?

```
var samin1 = "Cat";
var samin2 = "Dog";
var samin3 = "Elephant";
var samin4 = "Wolf";

var choosenvalue = 2;

var outputvalue = "samin"+"choosenvalue";
```

So I need to see "Dog".But I see as text "samin2";
Note: I dont use array.

Comment: Do ```var outputvalue = `${ samin2 }${ choosenvalue }`;```

Comment: The code you posted would produce `"saminchoosenvalue"`, not `"samin2"`. It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds very much like you want to learn about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead of naming your variables this way.

Comment: Seems to me like MattisS is trying to dynamically access a variable. This makes no sense. You could do it if the variables were in an array or object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the keyword `var` adds the variable to the global `window` object.

[Mdn var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description):

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution
>   context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables
>   declared outside any function, global. If you re-declare a JavaScript
>   variable, it will not lose its value.

```js
var samin1 = "Cat";
var samin2 = "Dog";
var samin3 = "Elephant";
var samin4 = "Wolf";

var choosenvalue = 2;

var outputvalue = window["samin"+choosenvalue];

console.log(outputvalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why would you need this, but it's possible to do using `eval`

```js
var samin1 = "Cat";
var samin2 = "Dog";
var samin3 = "Elephant";
var samin4 = "Wolf";

var choosenvalue = 2;

var outputvalue = eval("samin" + choosenvalue);

console.log(outputvalue);
```

Have you considered to use an array to store values instead?

```js
var animals = [
  "Cat",
  "Dog",
  "Elephant",
  "Wolf",
]

var choosenvalue = 1;

console.log(animals[choosenvalue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use object. You should not use `eval()` [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

And also avoid using global variables too. [read here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals)

```js
 let obj = 
 {'samin1' : "Cat",
'samin2': "Dog",
'samin3': "Elephant",
 'samin4': "Wolf"
 }

var choosenvalue = 2;

var outputvalue = obj[`samin${choosenvalue}`]

console.log(outputvalue)
```